Optimizing MariaDB Query When Re-Querying Same Table
I am trying to run a query that will get the last time a customer has placed an order. The catch is that the site allows people the ability to checkout both logged in and logged out. Additionally, I want to combine records for customers that have changed their email at some point.
I have a query that works (I think), but it involves three selects - one for the last order, one for logged in/out switches, and one for email switches. This is kind of slow on my database! What am I overlooking? How can I make this query more efficient and/or faster?
SELECT last, email, user_id 
FROM (
  SELECT last, email, user_id 
  FROM (
    SELECT time as last, email, 
      CASE WHEN user_id > 0 THEN CAST(user_id as CHAR(20))
      ELSE email
      END as user_id
    FROM   orders o1
    WHERE  time=(SELECT MAX(o2.time)
              FROM orders o2
              WHERE o1.email = o2.email)
    ORDER BY last DESC
  ) as o3
  GROUP BY email
) as o4
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY email

Edit: don't know how this will help, but here's the orders table, as requested:
create table orders(order_id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   user_id int(10) NOT NULL, 
   time int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
   email varchar(50) NOT NULL);
 PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`), KEY `userid` (`user_id`))
 ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6207584 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci


If user_id > 0 - that is logged user order, else user_id=0 - not logged user order? And not logged user must have email?

@ValNik Correct on both. A logged-in user also must have an email, if that matters.

please edit your question to show (as text, not image) output of show create table orders

"get the last time a customer has placed an order" - the query you show does this for all customers, not a customer.  which did you really mean?

please edit your question to show (as text, not image) output of show create table orders.  This provides essential information for answering your question accurately (as well as making it much easier to answer)

@ysth I intend to store the results of this query.  Schema added.

please do show create table orders, not just your original create statement; it provides important information

@ysth Added. For my professional growth, please let me know what information relevant to answering the question you have gained from this.

mostly the indexes, people are remarkably bad at providing accurate information about their indexes, they misstate them. also common is having data types that don't really match the usage. and the auto increment value gives an idea of how many records you have.  and it makes it easy for us to create the table and do at least rudimentary testing.

here I've learned that time is an int, and you will likely need an email index

Indexes are crucial to query performance. Check out https://use-the-index-luke.com/ for some good tutorials.

Update1.
In this example considered cases
1.User has orders with logged in and logged out with the same email.
2. User has orders with logged in with several email.
Index on ((email,user_id);) will be usefull for query.
time column data type does not matter.
Fiddle
and
select user_id,email,max_time
from(
  select max(user_id) user_id,email ,max(time) max_time
    ,row_number()over(partition by max(user_id) order by max(time) desc) rn_email
  from orders
  group by email
 )t
where rn_email=1 or user_id=0
order by email

Old part of answer:
You can range orders by time desc with partition by composite value (user_id or email).
To compare query performance, use 'EXPLAIN SELECT ...'
See example:
Test data



order_id
user_id
time
email




1
100
2024-09-01 14:00:00
user100@mail.com


2
100
2024-09-10 09:00:00
user100@mail.com


3
200
2024-09-12 09:00:00
user200@mail.com


4
300
2024-09-10 09:00:00
user300@mail.com


5
300
2024-09-12 09:00:00
user300-other@mail.com


6
400
2024-09-10 09:00:00
user400@mail.com


7
400
2024-09-12 09:00:00
user400-other@mail.com


8
400
2024-09-14 09:00:00
user400@mail.com


9
0
2024-09-11 09:00:00
user_x1@mail.com


10
0
2024-09-15 15:00:00
user_x1@mail.com


11
0
2024-09-10 09:00:00
user_x2@mail.com



Query example
select *
from(
  select *
    ,row_number()over(partition by case when user_id<>0 then CAST(user_id as varCHAR(50)) else email end 
                   order by time desc) rn
  from orders
)ranged_orders
where rn=1
order by email

Output



order_id
user_id
time
email
rn




2
100
2024-09-10 09:00:00
user100@mail.com
1


3
200
2024-09-12 09:00:00
user200@mail.com
1


5
300
2024-09-12 09:00:00
user300-other@mail.com
1


8
400
2024-09-14 09:00:00
user400@mail.com
1


10
0
2024-09-15 15:00:00
user_x1@mail.com
1


11
0
2024-09-10 09:00:00
user_x2@mail.com
1



fiddle
I think it is necessary to bring user_id and email to the same data type - the email data type (varchar(50) in example).
Another query
select *
from(
select * ,row_number()over(partition by user_id order by time desc) rn
from orders
where user_id<>0
  union all
select * ,row_number()over(partition by email order by time desc) rn
from orders
where user_id=0
)ranged_orders
where rn=1
order by email

possible (partially) covered by indexes. Example

I'm going to have to play with this a bit. For some reason, my data isn't combining like yours is (user_x1@mail.com shows up twice in the results, for example). The only difference I can see between my data and yours is that I use timestamps rather than dates, but I can't possibly see how that would change things. I'm going to see what I can figure out and report back.

Ok, I realized what's different here. If user_x1@mail.com has one purchase with user_id 0, and another with user_id 10 (logged in vs logged out), I want the query to be able to identify that these are the same customer - a common email OR a common user_id is enough to mark them as the same.

@MichaelW. but what happens when user_id 10 changes their email, then user_id 20 changes their email to user_x1@mail.com?  I recommend you go and update the user_id in the table how you want it, not try to do join logged in and not logged in orders in your query.  or at the least set an active_user_id column or something

@ysth I'm not concerned with users trading email addresses. Consider that an impossibility.

@ValNik I didn't notice you edit this, so sorry about that! This is looking very promising so far! What exactly is making this run so much better than my version?

Your query, I think, work well with indexes (email,time) and (email,user_id).Otherwise, there will most likely be several table scan instead of index scan or index seek. Usually, the subquery works well when applied to already filtered data. For example, if the table contains 1000 rows and only 10 after the filter, and a subquery needs to be applied to these 10 rows, instead of join 1000 rows. In general, see the execution plans with your real data.
